# UIBackGround modes & iBeacons: app rejected

Tags: ios, cllocation, clbeaconregion

Apple rejected an iBeacon app because I checked "Location updates" in background mode.

I made it quite obvious that the app monitors for iBeacons, this should also work in the background.

Apple's response:

"...Your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any features that require persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that require persistent location...."

I was under the impression that I need to switch on "location updates" as background mode, on order to be able to monitor for CLBeaconRegions in the background. Is that the case or not?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Solution is to remove the background mode. It's not required for iBeacon implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this research by Radius Networks](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html) and our own testing, you do not need to have `UIBackgroundModes=location ON` present in your Info.plist file for background region monitoring to work when using `CLBeaconRegion`.

Comment: But I think you need it if you want to do "Ranging". Aren't you?

Comment: @IvoStoyanov Yes, that's true.